# Force Jupyter to print and not display

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebooks in Visual Studio Code to present lab sessions for my Python programming course, albeit I am recommending students to work with `.py` files for themselves and their submissions. Ideally I would like the output of my Python cells to be identical to a Python console, and not pretty-printed by `display`.

I have already added

```
"jupyter.runStartupCommands": [
        "from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell",
        "InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = 'all'"
]
```

to `settings.json` to ensure I get all output but it is still passed to `display`. However, in a Python console, running `int` shows the representation `<class 'int'>`, whereas in the notebook it just shows `int`. Is there a way to force the Python cells to `print` and not `display`, so that the output is identical?

Comment: Hmmm... you should be able to clobber or shadow `IPython.display` and/or `IPython.core.display`, I'd think. Ironically, [someone posted today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75097183/8508004) what you are apparently want.

Comment: Your single provided example works as you want using the 'Xeus-Python Raw' kernel. To see that go [here](https://github.com/jupyter-xeus/xeus-python#) and open a temporary session by clicking the `launch binder` badge. From there, click the blue plus & open a notebook with the 'XPython Raw' choice. Typing `int` there shows `<class 'int'>` in the output. It works in the classic interface there, too , as you can see by switching interfaces via 'Help' > 'Launch Classic Notebook'. However, it doesn't seem to suppress all rich representation as a Pandas dataframe still displays as fancy rendering.

Comment: [This discussion](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-write-a-class-which-naturally-produce-a-latex-output-in-jupyter-notebook/17437/3?u=fomightez) and [section in documentation about integrating with Rich display](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#rich-display) makes me think you could run some code in a header of a notebook & get what you want, which I think is the 'standard repr()` being used, but I don't know quite the code to implement. I wonder if that last question would make a good post at [the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/)?