# Why is Jupyter suddenly showing dataframe as text-based?

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I've used jupyter notebook for a while now and if I do `df.head()` it always returns a nicely formatted table format. now I called the data and I get this!?? why? and how do I fix it?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("df.csv")

df.head()
```

```
   Unnamed: 0                                     address    date  \
0           0  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  2016Q3   
1           1  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  2016Q4   
2           2  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  2016Q4   
3           3  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  2017Q1   
4           4  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  2017Q1   

                                token_address       balance  decimals  \
0  0xd8912c10681d8b21fd3742244f44658dba12264e  2.000000e+19      18.0   
1  0xd8912c10681d8b21fd3742244f44658dba12264e  2.060000e+19      18.0   
2  0xe0b7927c4af23765cb51314a0e0521a9645f0e2a  4.500000e+11       9.0   
3  0xd8912c10681d8b21fd3742244f44658dba12264e  2.060000e+19      18.0   
4  0xe0b7927c4af23765cb51314a0e0521a9645f0e2a  4.571544e+11       9.0   

   token_price   tokens_USD  
0      1.99522    39.904400  
1      1.39913    28.822078  
2      8.53556  3841.002000  
3      1.33777    27.558062  
4     19.42000  8877.938149
```

I have tried the following but to no avail.

```
from IPython.display import display
display(df)
```

Comment: You'd have to provide a bit more information. Does what you posted represent a new notebook just started up and run so there's a fresh kernel? Or was there code above it that was run. Another way to go at that questions is to copy a notebook you know showed a dataframe well before and make a copy and re-run it. Does it not render the dataframe in the output nicely now? 'Suddenly' is a vague term. Did you update anything? It's always best to provide the versions of things involved. But looking into a few places without additional pointers, I'm not seeing anything obvious like a widespread bug.

Comment: In my tests, even an untrusted notebook (setting status should be in the upper right) displays a dataframe correctly, even if read from a csv file. I momentarily thought that setting could be involved but seems unlikely.